# Best way of storing a pair of values that need to be updated frequently in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a use case where I need to be storing a pair of values in Python where both values will need to be updated frequently.

Do I use a list or a tuple or something else? On one hand, a list is easier to update, since tuples are immutable and I will need to create a new tuple every time I update any one of the values. However, since I will not be appending anything to the list, and the size is fixed at 2, it feels like a tuple may be a better representation of what the object actually is.

Any insight? Thanks!

Comment: I'd just go list.  No reason to overthink things.

Comment: I don't feel that "the data changes size" is a necessary requirement to using a list. I use lists all the time that don't change size.

Comment: hmm, I thought... Let me check, just a sec.

Comment: @Kevin Huh. I read *somewhere* that you needed to do that. <cyberman voice> DELETE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a pair class?

```
class pair(object):
     def __init__(self,first,second):
         self.update(first,second)
     def update(self,first,second):
         self.first = first
         self.second = second
```

This clarifies it's only two objects, and that updates are welcome. If you want basic arithmetic with other pairs/lists/tuples you can implement that easily enough.

Answer (score 2):

Well there are several ways You could go about creating something like this, but I'd stick with a `list`. There's no reason to over think it.

> I will not be appending anything to the list, and the size is fixed at 2, it feels like a tuple may be a better representation of what the object actually is.

No. List do not have to change size. List can stay a constant size through your entire program. And the list has the distinct advantage, that it supports item assignment.

You could also consider looking into a `collections.namedtuple` if your looking for a light weight solution to @kabanus's. In fact, the [official Python documentation of `namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) shows an example with `namedtuple` using points:

```
>>> # Basic example
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p = Point(11, y=22)     # instantiate with positional or keyword arguments
>>> p[0] + p[1]             # indexable like the plain tuple (11, 22)
33
>>> x, y = p                # unpack like a regular tuple
>>> x, y
(11, 22)
>>> p.x + p.y               # fields also accessible by name
33
>>> p                       # readable __repr__ with a name=value style
Point(x=11, y=22)
```

Comment: In engineering, we have a principle -- The KISS principle -- Keep It Simple, Stupid. **If you have to be reminded of the KISS principle, it's true.**  Same here. Don't overthink it. Use lists. You have my vote.

Comment: @Blacksilver What do you mean? Are you implying I'm overthinking my answer? If so, how?

Comment: No. I'm talking to User :)

Comment: @Blacksilver Oh, OK. Sorry :)

Comment: Perfectly reasonable assumption. That's prob what I would have thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about performance and want to name the fields, use [`__slots__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots):

```
class datum(object):
    __slots__ = ['x', 'y']
```

Now you have a simple, high-performance, compact type which does not require dictionary lookup for field access.

But if you care about performance and do not want to name the fields, you may as well stick with `list`.

Answer (score 0):

A list is perfectly sufficient here. You shouldn't discount it as a possibility just because you always have the same amount of data.

I don't feel that using a tuple is appropriate here, because 1) generally, you use immutable types for data that doesn't change, and your data *is* changing. And 2) If you have to update one value independent of the other, the syntax becomes needlessly verbose. Compare the tuple syntax:

```
my_pair = (new_first_value, my_pair[1])
```

To the list syntax:

```
my_pair[0] = new_first_value
```